# how can i disable interaction on windows phone page while loading data?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

how can I make a windows phone page isenabled = false?

data loading takes sometime, and I want the user to wait for that without messing around on the page, can I maybe use the:

```
HomePage.IsHitTestVisibleProperty
```

somehow?
thanx

Answer (score 7):

While the page is loading, you can put a grid w/ transparent background on top of the elements on the page with IsHitTestVisible = true. That way it will capture all user interaction without blocking visibly.